# Flutter Twilio Conversation chat title body are null when send text

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, twilio, twilio-conversations

I am implementing Twilio Conversations chat in Flutter. I have configured notification in Android according to document. Register token for notification. There is one issue that when I tried to listen for messages from the notification event I am getting data from the message event but getting null object for title and body. Does anyone have idea about it?

Please refer code I am trying to implement.

```dart
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(_onMessage);

 void _onMessage(RemoteMessage event) {
    Log.debug('_onMessage -> ${event.notification?.title} -> ${event.notification?.body}');
    Log.debug('_onMessage -> ${event.data}');
    Log.debug('_onMessage -> ${event.messageType}');
  }
```

Comment: I don't have any experience with Flutter, otherwise I'd love to help. If you don't get a response here, can I recommend you try the [project's Discord channel](https://discord.gg/MWnu4nW) for help too.